# Error when openning a webpart

Tags: web-part, discussion-board

I've installed Discussion Board Plus on my SharePoint 2013 server.

and I've created a forum.

when I go to the forum I get the below error.

TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'RenderField'

I've debugged the forum page and came up with this.

I have bamboo video library installed on this sharepoint server too.

I think there is a conflict between these two:
[image]
[image]

I've tried uninstalling all the other bamboo webparts and only having the discussion forum webpart. it didn't help.
I've posted my question on their forum, they didn't help.
they said to open a ticket but I can't since I haven't bought the webpart yet.

Comment: Would you buy the car if during the test-drive a wheel fell off. And the vendor says: Buy the car, then we help you?

Comment: that's what I'm saying! but this webpart really matches our need.

Comment: No, you are saying you want to fix the car yourself..

Comment: For US$ 1995,- *per server* you can hire a whole team on [Freelancer.com](http://Freelancer.com) and have a custom car built in India.

Comment: btw this works on our test server